# IE BHO browser extension: how to get cookies when they're set, removed, etc

Tags: internet-explorer, bho, iwebbrowser2

I'm writing an extension for Internet Explorer, and am wondering how to programmatically detect in a session what cookies get set, deleted, modified, etc. per domain.

I understand that cookies are handled on a WinInet level, and not necessarily IE BHO, extensions, etc.

But is it possible to to snoop cookies per instance (IWebBrowser2), or per process?

Have looked into a few ideas, Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols, etc.  As of now I'm even considering IAT table patching, but figured I'd ask for a more elegant solution before.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any elegant solution to this, only viable one is to patch vtbl for several classes in urlmon.dll.

I understand it has been some time since you asked the question, however I'm in the same boat right now with a fairly complicated extension. I'm having problems with capturing all cookie content as well. Can we chat about this sometime?